# Error:'Answer' object has no attribute 'get'?

Tags: django, modelform

I'm using Django 1.11.
when I'm using this code it works with me but when I'm trying to add new condition besides in this case (else) I get this error:
 [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYf37.png) 
I want to put a new condition to stop anyone could put (get method) on my page, How can so?

favourite.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Favourite Page</title>
    <style>
        input {padding: 8px;margin-top: 5px}
        label {display: inline-block}
        .input {display: inline-block}

    </style>
</head>
<body>

    {% if form_data %}
        {{ form_data.question }}

    {% else %}
    <form action="{% url 'market:favourite' %}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% include 'market/template-form.html' %}
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
    {% endif %}



</body>
</html>
```

views.py

```
def favourite(request):
    context = {}
    form = Answer
    context['form'] = form
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = form(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid:
            form.save(commit=False)
            return render(request, 'market/favourite.html', {'form_data': form.cleaned_data})
    else:
        form = Answer()
        return form
    return render(request, 'market/favourite.html', {'form': form})<br>
```

forms.py

```
from .models import Question
from django import forms


class Answer(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = ['question']
```

models.py

```
CHOICE = [(1, 'Si'), (2, 'No')]

class Question(models.Model):
    question = models.IntegerField(choices=CHOICE, default=1, blank=False)
```

Comment: `form = Answer`? Can you please share your models/forms/...?

Comment: You furthermore `return form`, but that is not a valid item to return in a view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The core problem is that you `return form`. You can not return a form as result of a view function, it needs to be a `HttpResponse` object.

That being said, your code contains some items who are a bit "problematic":

1. it is better to name your forms with a `Form` suffix, since otherwise you can generate a "name clash" with a model named `Answer`;
2. you pass a reference to the `Answer` to the context, not the form object. That is useful if it turns out the form is invalid;
3. in order to check if the form is valid, you need to *call* the [**`is_valid()`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.is_valid), not obtain the method reference, since that always has truthiness `True`;
4. in case the form is valid, you likely want to *commit* the result, since otherwise your form has not much use;
5. in case the POST request is valid, you normally return a *redirect* to implement the [*Post/Redirect/Get* pattern [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get);
6. you do not do anything with your context, since you simply construct a dictionary and render with that as context.

A better view would look like:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def favourite(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # rename Answer to AnswerForm
        form = AnswerForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():  # call the method
            form.save()
            return redirect('some-view-name')
    else:
        form = AnswerForm()
    return render(request, 'market/favourite.html', {'form': form})
```

Here you need to replace *`'some-view-name'`* with the name of a view to redirect to in case of a successful view.

Comment: ok, but the actual goal to this code is after to (get method) I want to print out the outputs of my code on the page the question is: if I used (redirect) how could I show my code prints out. in this case, I use form_data.cleaned_data to show my output and it emerges without putting (redirect) but I get an error when I put (else) so, I think that it doesn't matter if I used something like (redirect) or not. How I see my output of the code if used (redirect) or didn't?

Comment: @abdelhamedabdin: you can here, for testing purposes return a `HttpResponse(repr(form.cleaned_data))`. for example. The `.get()` error is triggered because the middleware calls `.get()` on the view result.